# Not able to create Salesforce Project in VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

I have installed Salesforce CLI and Visual Studio code but when i tried to create a Salesforce project with Manifest I get this error:

> (17:02:00.225 sfdx force:project:create --projectname DevSandbox --outputdir c:\Users\prabhat.jha\Documents\C3SDevMetadata\DevOrg --template standard --manifest ended with error spawn sfdx ENOENT
>   Salesforce CLI is not installed. Install it from https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli

[image]

Comment: It seems that your computer isn't convinced that you have installed the CLI though. Have you [verified your CLI install](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_install_cli_verify)?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure salesforce CLI environment variable is set. If not go to set an environment variable in your system. Once set the environmental variable restart your device.

Comment: Please be specific. What environment variable are you telling the poster to set?

Comment: Hello Everyone,I installed it successfully and it was the Product Issue as explained in this Post https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/383.Thanks all for your Time for suggestion.

Comment: Salesforce CLI installed path variable like this "C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI".

Answer (score 0):

It was a Product Issue as explained in Post https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/383
Please check this once before you spent days on fixing this like me.
Hope it saves times for other.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was I had a space in folder path and that is why it was complaining. 
c:\Users\Salman Zafar\EnvironmentName

Once I removed spaces in the path it worked. c:\EnvironmentName.